# SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: exception, apache-spark

I ran my program on Spark but a SparkException thrown:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1242)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:277)
    at com.ynu.App$.main(App.scala:42)
    at com.ynu.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
... 12 more
```

Could somebody tells me how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: Did you extend `App` and write your codes in an Object directly? If so, could you use `main` method instead?

Comment: Yes I extend App,but my program running on cluster why should I use main method?

Comment: `extends App` may make some Closure functions store a reference to SparkContext or other non-serializable instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best Answer for this is to Use the `Extends App` in your Scala class it worked for me.